# owl carousel один элемент

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, owl-carousel

Нужна помощь по шаблону OneTech https://htmlcode.ru/themes/template/424-Onetech.html
В нем имеется карусель Owl Carousel версии 2. Как в цикле foreach вывести элементы, чтобы они не клонировались если в цикле менее 6 элементов?

```html
<!-- Recently Viewed Item -->
<?php foreach ($related as $item): ?>
<div class="owl-item">
    <div class="viewed_item discount d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center text-center">
        <div class="viewed_image"><img src="/images/<?=$item['img']?>" alt="<?=$item['title']?>"></div>
        <div class="viewed_content text-center">
            <div class="viewed_price"></div>
            <div class="viewed_name"><a href="/product/<?=$item['alias']?>"><?=$item['title']?></a></div>
        </div>
        <ul class="item_marks">
            <li class="item_mark item_discount">-25%</li>
            <li class="item_mark item_new">new</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Кастомизировать библиотеки js я не умею, поэтому прошу помощи. Спасибо

Comment: они клонируются через значения infinity в owl-carousel

Answer (score 0):

По умолчанию выставлены вот такие настройки. Когда в цикле 1 элемент, то в виде он отображается 6 раз

```js
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.owl-item').owlCarousel({
            items: 1,
            loop: true,
            margin: 10,
            autoplay: true,
            autoplayTimeout: 1000,
            autoplayHoverPause: true
        })
    });
</script>
```